Why are my pages being excluded by Google for noindex tags that don't exist?
I have a lot of URLs that in Google Search Console seem to be showing as Excluded by ‘noindex’ tag. However, this meta tag does not seem to exist in the pages themselves.
An example is https://www.savvycompare.co.uk/compare-deals/pay-monthly/Samsung/Galaxy-S24-Ultra/
Is there something I'm missing? Or how can I resolve this?

There are several ways to implement noindex, such as .htaccess files (and presumably the Microsoft equivalent). We're not going to be able to find that for you.

@isherwood wouldn't that show in the headers of the page though?

Server configuration doesn't add page head markup. It just tells the crawler what it expects.

In the GSC URL inspection for one of the URLs, look at the HTML that Google picked up. Does it have noindex in it?
It's also possible to have a noindex in the http headers, but I don't see that.

There's a good chance the data is outdated (in my experience those reports aren't updated very frequently, especially if the URLs aren't regularly crawled). I can't see any noindex directive via my browser (server-side HTML, rendered HTML, or HTTP headers) so this is probably the case assuming your website isn't serving differently depending on user-agent/IP.
As Tony suggested, try inspecting an example URL in GSC and see if it reports the noindex in a live test. If not, validating the issue in GSC should "fix" it although it might take some time for all of them to be re-crawled and indexed.
Failing that, you'll probably have better luck with asking the GSC Help Community.
